# How to fix the error in GML: non-planar polygon distance

Tags: error-handling, geometry, gml, city

I have validated the GML data in the CityDoctor. It found the error "GE_P_NON_PLANAR_POLYGON_DISTANCE_PLANE" in nearly all of the buildings. Is there a way to fix such an error?

I tried to access CityDoctor's healing module. However, the module is still in development.

The error and the healing are described in the link: https://gitlab.com/volkercoors/CiD4Sim/-/wikis/healing/GE_P_NON_PLANAR_POLYGON_DISTANCE_PLANE